# Telemetry: Is there some statistics about Ubuntu desktop usage provided by Canonical?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 17.04, canonical

Maybe they don't share real values (like, there is X number of **Ubuntu** installations used daily) but at least `%` ones?

I'm interested about the repartition of the versions used (for example, there is `8%` of `12.04`, `16%` of `14.04`, `51%` of `16.04`, `26%` of `17.04`. I'm guessing here) and also the desktop ENV used (`80%` is running **Unity**, `7%` **KDE**, `4%` **Cinnamon**, etc).

Does anyone know where I can find such numbers?

Steam conducts a monthly survey so [we have some numbers](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey?platform=linux) there but it is a small amount of **Ubuntu** users who have steam, and gamers are very specific users (very **up-to-date**, etc).

Comment: 17.10 is now out, I'd love to up this question. Is there anyone from Canonical that I can ping?

Answer (score 2):

There's none (that I know). Few reasons:

1. Telemetry was introduced only in 18.04, so there's no way to pick the data from previous versions easily
2. Even if, according to their [Official Telemetry Blog post](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/06/22/a-first-look-at-desktop-metrics) opt-in rate was only ~67% (and thank you, Canonical for making this opt-in!)
3. Even if they measured downloads (which many often measure) downloads doesn't reflect usage, since some ISOs are often used for virtual machine

I'm afraid your best bet is to look into some stats like browser ones, game platform ones and join the dots togthter for approximate results. There's no report that has exactly what you're looking for I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As of a couple releases ago we have a sub site on [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/statistics) with statistics. It has graphs on several items (I listed the popular one at the end):

- **How many users opted in?** 66% Opt-In
- **Where are Ubuntu users?** (22.3% are in the USA)
- **What language do they use?** (59% English)
- **Desktop specs** (amd64 98%)
- **What graphics setup do users have?**
- **Popular screen sizes** (1920x1080 = 28%)
- **Pixel density** (160 for 55%)
- **What CPU and memory do users have?** (1-3 for 66%)
- **Size of RAM (GB)** (1-4 for 51%)
- **What physical disks do people have?** (0 - 499Gb for 79%)
- **Partition type** (54% do "Erase device andinstall")
- **Size of partitions (GB)**
- **Number of partitions** (50% have 1 partition)

More on the metrics on [Will Cooke's blog](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/06/22/a-first-look-at-desktop-metrics?_ga=2.264573391.1994049076.1555313412-1925708356.1541605699) with the title "A first look at desktop metrics"

> I'm interested about the repartition of the versions used. Does anyone know where I can find such numbers?

Is not among them so those numbers are unavailable as of today.

> Is there anyone from Canonical that I can ping?

Will Cooke would be the most obvious one.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however it doesn't contain anything about the DE used and those stats are already pretty outdated today (almost one year ago).

Comment: If a lot of people ask him he would be foolish to not include it or at least give arguments to why it can or is not included :)